# quartz 2.1.7 giving NoClassDefFoundError in ant project

Tags: ant, log4j, quartz-scheduler

We are using quartz in our ant project, and for logging we are using log4j.

Still now we are using quartz 1.5.2, and there were no problem. Now we want to upgrade it to quartz 2.1.7.

When we replace our quartz-all-1.5.2.jar with quartz-all-2.1.7.jar file, and starte the service, we are getting the following error

```
[QuartzService] Create QuartzService(Quartz)...

WARN  [ServiceController] Problem creating service user:service=QuartzService,name=Quartz
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
       at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.<init>(StdSchedulerFactory.java:261)
       at org.quartz.ee.jmx.jboss.QuartzService.createService(QuartzService.java:220)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:260)
       at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:243)
       [...]
```

we tried quartz 1.6.6 and 1.7.3, and we didn't have any issue with that. But from 1.8.4 onward we are getting the above error

Now  the problem is, we are not using slf4j for logging. so,

1. Is there anyway to use quartz 2.1.7 with log4j only?
2. If we need to use slf4j, can we redirect logging to log4j somehow?
3. Can we do this in ant?

The project is ant project, not maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quartz 2.1.7 uses log4j with slf4j, so I think you need slf4j 1.6.1 (api, slf4j-log4j12)

Look at the dependencies of [version 1.5.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/quartz/quartz/1.5.2) and [version 2.1.7](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.1.7).